React Native Expo Navigation Drawer icon is not showing up in firebase deployment environment
I am using Navigation Drawer to create a sidebar menu. It renders fine when running it locally but when deploying it to the google server - https://cancer-hacked.web.app/ - The Navigation Menu Icon in the top left of the screen doesn't show. Looking at the source code on the google server there is no img tag which there is in my local environment.
Local App - 
Firebase Deployed App -

Here is my main app file - index.js
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import CancerHomepageWebWrapper from './CancerHomepageWebWrapper';
import ChemoHomepageWebWrapper from './ChemoHomepageWebWrapper';
import GeneHomepageWebWrapper from './GeneHomepageWebWrapper';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Cancer">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Cancer" component={CancerHomepageWebWrapper} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Chemo" component={ChemoHomepageWebWrapper} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Gene" component={GeneHomepageWebWrapper} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

And my deploy script
npx expo export -p web
mv dist/index.html src/main/www/index.html
mv dist/metadata.json src/main/www/
mv dist/favicon.ico src/main/www/
rm -rf src/main/www/assets
mv dist/assets src/main/www/assets
rm -rf src/main/www/_expo
mv dist/_expo src/main/www/_expo
firebase deploy


I got the side bar icon showing up in my firebase deployment. I was able to override the image tag on the side bar menu icon providing a path to src/main/www/images/toogle-drawer-icon.png. My main app file index.js now looks like this:
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import CancerHomepageWebWrapper from './CancerHomepageWebWrapper';
import ChemoHomepageWebWrapper from './ChemoHomepageWebWrapper';
import GeneHomepageWebWrapper from './GeneHomepageWebWrapper';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const CustomHeader = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
        <Image
          source={require('./images/toggle-drawer-icon.png')}
          style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator  initialRouteName="Cancer" screenOptions={{
               headerLeft: (props) => <CustomHeader/>
         }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Cancer" component={CancerHomepageWebWrapper} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Chemo" component={ChemoHomepageWebWrapper} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Cancer Genes" component={GeneHomepageWebWrapper} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

